# how to get sqlite records before whole query finished

Tags: database, sqlite, optimization

I Wondering if it is possible to get few results of sqlite select query while query still in Process and not finished it.

For example if I have a query with Thousands of records, can I get the first set and display it meanwhile?

Thanks,
Kobi

Comment: What language/framework are you using to access the database?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do anything special to get this effect.

SQLite computes result records dynamically, i.e., `sqlite3_step` does only as much work as is needed to get the next result record.

(This does not help much if you do things like sorting, where the first record to be returned might be the last one read from the database.)